# jquery, как правильно найти первый родительський элемент

Tags: jquery

у меня есть даный HTML

```
 <div id="popup-ship-it" class="fixed-overlay fixed-overlay__modal">
        <div class="modal">
            <div class="modal_container">
                <p class="close-popup">X</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
/*popup */
portalBox.find('#ship-it').on('click', function () {
    jQuery("#popup-ship-it").show();
});

portalBox.find('.close-popup').on('click', function(){
    console.log(jQuery('.close-popup').parent());
    //jQuery("#popup-ship-it").hide();
});
```

я в ответ получаю div с id `modal_container`, как мне получить главного отца? Тоесть div где id = `popup-ship-it`

Comment: `closest()` или `parents()`. ваш `parent` берет непосредственно родителя

Comment: Главное - в `closest` или `parents` указать фильтр/селектор, по которому выберется именно нужный родитель. Если такового в вёрстке нет - надо добавить